# Read out data from XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

Hi i am having problems reading out the nodes of a XML file? I cant find the child nodes in the XML. This code finds no nodes. if i change:

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Properties");
```

To

```
XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//NewDataSet");
```

Then i get two nodes returned i get properties and requestdata, but i want the properties child nodes.

Could some one please tel me why i cant see the child nodes of properties and please help me to find them.

---

Here is my C# code.

```
if (File.Exists("C://Users//Shaun//Documents//Visual Studio 2010//Projects//LightStoneTestService//LightStoneTestService//FileTest//Testdo.xml")) //In bin and Debug
    {
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDoc.Load("C://Users//Shaun//Documents//Visual Studio 2010//Projects//LightStoneTestService//LightStoneTestService//FileTest//Testdo.xml");

    XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Properties");

    foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
      {
        int Count = 0;
        int Max = node.ChildNodes.Count;
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes) //For each child node in FieldData
         {
           if (ArrayProperties[Count].LightStoneTag == childNode.Name)
          {
            ArrayProperties[Count].Value = node.SelectSingleNode(ArrayProperties[Count].LightStoneTag).InnerText;
          }
           Count = Count + 1;
         }
      }
```

---

Here is my XML file i am trying to read all the nodes in properties:

```
  <NewDataSet>
  <RequestData xmlns="RequestData">
    <Req_ID>fe0bc7ab-1dc9-4526-bd29-b522ff13e162</Req_ID>
  </RequestData>
  <Properties xmlns="Properties">
    <sr_id>19374149</sr_id>
    <prop_id>9841107</prop_id>
    <DEED_ID>21</DEED_ID>
    <PROPTYPE_ID>2</PROPTYPE_ID>
    <SS_ID>2315</SS_ID>
    <NAD_ID>3048001</NAD_ID>
    <property_type>SS</property_type>
    <PROVINCE>GA</PROVINCE>
    <MUNICNAME>CITY OF JOHANNESBURG</MUNICNAME>
    <DEEDTOWN>ALLENS NEK</DEEDTOWN>
    <SECTIONAL_TITLE>SS GREENHILLS</SECTIONAL_TITLE>
    <UNIT>15</UNIT>
    <ERF>627</ERF>
    <PORTION>0</PORTION>
    <BUYER_NAME>FOURIE MARION ROBB</BUYER_NAME>
    <FIRSTNAME>MARION</FIRSTNAME>
    <MIDDLENAME>ROBB</MIDDLENAME>
    <SURNAME>FOURIE</SURNAME>
    <PERSON_TYPE_ID>PP</PERSON_TYPE_ID>
    <BUYER_IDCK>7402110182087</BUYER_IDCK>
    <MUNIC_ID>74</MUNIC_ID>
    <PROV_ID>8</PROV_ID>
    <STREET_NUMBER>973</STREET_NUMBER>
    <STREET_NAME>MAIN</STREET_NAME>
    <STREET_TYPE>ROAD          </STREET_TYPE>
    <PO_CODE>1709</PO_CODE>
    <User_ID>2443598d-948b-4322-bd91-d39f57bec1b6</User_ID>
    <SS_Number>29</SS_Number>
    <SS_UnitNoFrom>1</SS_UnitNoFrom>
    <SS_UnitTo>26</SS_UnitTo>
    <Size>65</Size>
    <X>27.919578</X>
    <Y>-26.125565</Y>
    <SUBURB>ALLENS NEK</SUBURB>
    <Registrar>J</Registrar>
    <Title_Deed_No>ST28776/2004</Title_Deed_No>
    <Reg_Date>20040519</Reg_Date>
    <TownShip>ALLENS NEK</TownShip>
    <Purchase_Price>236500</Purchase_Price>
    <Purchase_Date>20031020</Purchase_Date>
    <Bond_Number>SB37369/2006</Bond_Number>
    <Township_alt>ALLEN'S NEK EXT 32</Township_alt>
    <RE>false</RE>
  </Properties>
</NewDataSet>
```

---

**New Part**

I am having troubles pulling out the inner text, my code is in the foreach above, my app keeps breaking on the line:

```
ArrayProperties[Count].Value = node.SelectSingleNode(ArrayProperties[Count].LightStoneTag).InnerText;
```

Could someone please show me how to pull out a value from an XML File.

Comment: What is your problem? Please ask a more detailed question!

Comment: @derape ok added more detail, What i am trying to achieve is to read all those child nodes of properties in my for-each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample code

code for  loading the file

```
private const string XML_FILE_NAME = "sample.xml";
public static XmlDocument LoadSampleXML()
    {
        XmlDocument oXmlDocument = null;
        try
        {

            oXmlDocument= new XmlDocument();
            oXmlDocument.Load(XML_FILE_NAME);
            return oXmlDocument;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return oXmlDocument;
        }
    }
```

Following code you can use to get child nodes

```
 private const string XML_NODE_PROP = "Properties";
 XmlDocument oXmlDocument = null;
 oXmlDocument = LoadSampleXML();
 XmlNodeList oXMlNodeList = oXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName(XML_NODE_PROP);

 foreach (XmlNode oXmlNodeItem in oXMlNodeList)
            {
               // DoSomething
            }
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting the inner text out of the XML file you can check my code under the foreach above, it keeps breaking on this line: ArrayProperties[Count].Value = node.SelectSingleNode(ArrayProperties[Count].LightStoneTag).InnerText;

Answer (score 1):

No big XML-knowledge at my side, but since `Properties` is a childnode of `NewDataSet`, my guess is that you first have to get the `Properties` node and with that you can probably get the nodes you want.

Comment: I thin you are right, but how would i go about getting the child node of a child node?

Comment: @Pommy I see that Manish already posted the sample code. I couldn't have helped you with that. Never read an XML before. Only posted an educated guess after looking at the structure of the XML-file. ;-)